# Doing a union on two tables, but renaming columns that may have the same name in postgres and dropping others

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union

I am doing a union on two tables that have some of the same column names. So, say they look something like this:

```
table1
=========
_id
fk_id
name
details
createdAt
updatedAt

table2
=========
_id
fk_id
name
age
details
createdAt
updatedAt
```

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
SELECT * FROM "table1"
    JOIN table2
    ON table1."fk_id"=table2."fk_id";
```

Currently I obviously get repeated columns. So here is what I want to do:

1- The table2's columns `name` and `details`, I would like to rename to `t1_name` and `t2_details` respectively

2- I would like to drop table2's `_id`, `fk_id`, `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enumerate the columns that you want to retain, and alias them as needed:

```
select
    t1._id,
    t1.fk_id,
    t1.name t1_name,
    t1.details t1_details,
    t1.createdAt,
    t1.updatedAt,
    t2.name t2_name,
    t2.age,
    t2.details t2_details
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.fk_id = t2.fk_id
```

Comment: The thing is, there are a lot more properties in my actual table than in the example. Would there be a way to maybe specify to select all the columns from table1 but only a few from table2?

Comment: Update: figured it out by messing around, just did `t1.*` to get all properties and renamed t2's as I pleased. This worked perfectly. Thanks!